# Cleaning data with conflicting data points

Tags: data-cleaning

I have a dataset from a legacy system that is entered by various entities (internal technicians, internal billing clerks, customers, and some system-derived entries). The goal is to deliver cost per hour on this equipment.

The data contains 3 important fields: sequence#, meter-reading, reading-date. These 3 fields are often completely contradictory. Our accounting system is monthly so my approach is to come up with monthly average usage to compare to maintenance cost.

There may be multiple entries made within any month and also several consecutive months with no entries since some of this equipment is used regularly year round while some is used seasonally. Finding a single monthly average usage is not very useful in these cases.

I have tried to generate sequence numbers for the meter-reading and reading-date fields and then removing all rows where 2 or all 3 sequence numbers are in disagreement but found too many cases where the very first reading entry was actually wrong so ended up with worse skewing than the untidy data.

In short, I'm out of ideas on how to proceed. It may just be impossible to come up with a good clean dataset. Any help is much appreciated.

John

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I think that this is entirely about expert knowledge: if the application requires a well cleaned-up dataset, then ideally you have to investigate as precisely as possible who entered data and how they used to do it, in order to understand the possible problems. I mean actually going to ask the people, not only trying to make sense of the data on your own. Obviously this could be a huge task... If this is not possible, then you can only build a system on this imperfect data, maybe after cleaning up the most obvious issues.

Comment: Thanks, @Erwan. The reasons for the mistakes boil down to fat-fingers and zero validation in the legacy app. Often there are transposed digits in the month or year. Customers often uploaded batches of readings gathered over a month and may or may not include the actual date of entry for each reading. These issues have been addressed and the data is much better now, but there are literally millions of readings that I'd like to use for ML. I guess I was hoping someone has worked through a similar problem and might have some insight.